# xctk:IntegerUpDown custom style to hide ButtonSpinner

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

On the [xctk:IntegerUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution_35/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml), I would like the textbox border and the ButtonSpinner to only be visible when focused or mouseover.
It is easy enough to turn the border on/off using a *<Style.Triggers>* section.
It is also possible to control the *ShowButtonSpinner* property.

However, the content of the TextBox jumps to the right if I set *ShowButtonSpinner*=False.
I would like to simply hide the ButtonSpinner without TextBox contents jumping around.

Like this:

[image]

How can I get access to the appropriate property?

Comment: Sounds like the default behavior of this control is to actually get rid of the up down arrows and leave the size of the entire control the same which makes your value jump to the now available space to the right. You can try reducing the size of the control when it is focused to the size - sizeof(arrows) and restore it when it is losing focus but that is an ugly workaround

Comment: I had not thought of that workaround.  Yes, it is ugly; especially if the size is determined by an outer object...

Answer (score 0):

*your question helped me to find `ShowButtonSpinner` property which I needed to hide up and down buttons*

i can suggest a workaround with setting a fixed `Padding` for content when buttons are hidden. Value `0,0,17,0` seems ok to me (Win7, wpf toolkit version v2.6.0.0)

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown.Style>
    <Style TargetType="xctk:IntegerUpDown">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,17,0"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowButtonSpinner" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="ShowButtonSpinner" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</xctk:IntegerUpDown.Style>
```

---

another simple thing is to align text to left side via property

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown TextAlignment="Left"/>
```